# Video Player in Galaxy Note 10.1 keeps starting itself when connected to computer through USB

Tags: video, auto-start, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

The Video Player app that came with Galaxy Note 10.1 will start at the background when connected to a Windows computer through USB. And there's no option in that app to disable it. It always appear in Task Manager when connected. Is there any way to disable this auto-start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the video player registered a listener to be notified on "USB connected". If you want to keep the app but get rid of that annoyance, the only way goes via root. You won't need a custom ROM for that -- just an app like [Autorun Manager PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun.pro) which allows you to disable listeners of any app:

[image: AutoRun Manager]

As the screenshot shows, *AutoRun Manager* lists up all apps along with their registered listeners. Check here for your video player app, find the responsible listener, and remove the checkmark in front of it. That should do it.

If you do so for some apps, and some day decide to remove *AutoRun Manager*, *your restrictions would persist* unless you reset them *before* uninstalling *ARM* (the app has a "revert" option, and can even revert all changes at once). If you forgot that, and want to re-enable disabled listeners, the only way is to re-install the affected app (not *ARM*, that won't help as it remembered its actions in its settings, which are removed when you uninstall the app).

Answer (score 0):

If this is the stock system, then the only way to change it would be to root it and install a Custom ROM (or remove the stock video app and replace it with a 3rd party video player).